# PHP - Isset not working and logic is right

Tags: php, isset

Ok this is a really stupid one but something is definitely wrong.

I have a php script that needs to check for 2 variables ($token and $pid)

```
if(isset($token) && isset($pid)){
$ppurl = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$GetExpressCheckoutDetails = $ppurl."?USER=".$apiuser."&PWD=".$apipwd."&SIGNATURE=".$apisig."&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&VERSION=78&TOKEN=".$token;
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $GetExpressCheckoutDetails);
$info = parsePPResponse(curl_exec($cURL));
die (what);
}
```

Still, when I access the script directly without any variable it still runs that code.

The same way, if I add this before:

```
if(!isset($token)){ die(novar); }
```

It will still run the code and die with the message what .

This doesn't make any sense, anyone have a clue why this might be happenning ?

Comment: add a `var_dump` for both variables above the `if(isset(` line and update the question with the output

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex. 

The output is :

    string(0) "" int(0) what

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your question?  If so, it'd be good to mark it as accepted so the responder gets credit and others who view this in the future know which solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description, my best guess is that $pid was actually set and is just empty.

Before your `if(isset($token) && isset($pid)){` run the following code:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r(get_defined_vars());
print '</pre>';
```

Then see if $pid or $token is present in the page output.  If it is, you might need to change your condition to use the empty() function instead of isset().

Comment: @Vaviloff 

Thanks that was most useful .

[pid] => 0
[token] => 

For some reason pid is being set to 0.

What's curious is if I do : 

if(!isset($token)){
die(novar); }


It will still run the code instead of dying with novar msg

Comment: Token set as empty.. u need to chk ! Empty () @rdang

Comment: @devpro

Yes already did that , updated question below.

Strangely though, token is empty and if I do isset for token only it doesn't work.

Comment: if you want it to execute when it is NOT empty make sure you use    !empty() not empty() or alternatively you can do if(isset($token) && $token !='')

Comment: @Rdang Try `if(isset($token) && !empty($token) && isset($pid) && !empty($pid)){

Answer (score 1):

```
!empty($token)
```

might work better

Comment: empty will work better for my case and solves my issue thanks.

But I will still leave the question up as this seems like a rather unusual situation and it may be helpful for other people experiencing the same issue in the future.

//if(empty($token)){
//die(notoken); }

Already checked with vardump and print_r(get_defined_vars()); as sa289 sugested, and although it's empty it still won't run.

  [token] => 

 string(0)

Comment: @rdang my friend use var_dump($token); u will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `var_dump($token)` to make sure that the variable is really not set and that you are really editing the same file you think you are editing (happened to me)